# AngularJS Directive Scope variables undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

Here is the relevant JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/9Ltyru6a/3/

In the fiddle, I have set up a controller and a directive that I want to use to call a callback whenever a value is change. I know that Angular has an ng-change directive, but I want something more akin to the standard onchange event (that gets triggered once when the field is blurred).

Controller:

```
var Controllers;
    (function (Controllers) {
    var MyCtrl = (function () {
        function MyCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.vm = this;
        }

        MyCtrl.prototype.callback = function (newValue) {
            alert(newValue);
        };

        return MyCtrl;
    })();
    Controllers.MyCtrl = MyCtrl;
})(Controllers || (Controllers = {}));
```

Directive:

```
var Directives;
(function (Directives) {
    function OnChange() {
        var directive = {};
        directive.restrict = "A";
        directive.scope = {
            onchange: '&'
        };
        directive.link = function (scope, elm) {
            scope.$watch('onChange', function (nVal) {
                elm.val(nVal);
            });
            elm.bind('blur', function () {
                var currentValue = elm.val();
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.onchange({ newValue: currentValue });
                });
            });
        };
        return directive;
    }
    Directives.OnChange = OnChange;
})(Directives || (Directives = {}));
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <button ng-click="vm.callback('Works')">Test</button>
        <input onchange="vm.callback(newValue)"></input>
    </div>
</body>
```

The button works, so I can safely say (I think) that the controller is fine. However, whenever I change the value of the input field and unfocus, I get a "vm is undefined" error.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: why don't you just use `ng-blur`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur#!/

Comment: That's definitely an option, but I eventually want to encapsulate the logic of checking whether or not the value actually changed within this directive.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Angular can handle dirty checking for you as well......

Comment: What I mean is that, I want to be able to just add "onchange = callback" to any input field, and not have the controller worry about deciding whether the field actually changed or not. If there is a way to do that with the onblur directive, then I'd definitely mark that as an answer.

Comment: If you comment out the line elm.val(nVal); you no longer get the error. What are you trying to achieve with that line? It seems unneeded as I'm not sure what you're $watching

Comment: does using angular form validation options (`ng-dirty`, for example) not do what you want?

Comment: @MathewBerg I actually continue to get the error even with that line commented out.

Comment: @Claies It might, but I can't seem to find any documentation on that directive

Comment: it looks like you have an answer that might fix the directive you are creating, but I still feel like you're re-inventing the wheel here.

Comment: @Claies I'd love some more info on that. Please provide some reference to that directive you were talking about, because I honestly can't find any information anywhere. If it does allow you to call a callback iff a value has changed, without having to have the controller worry about verifying that the value has changed, then I'll use it in a heartbeat. Less code to maintain.

Comment: If there's no directive that does that, then I don't mind putting it in a directive. Otherwise, that same logic (of checking whether a field changed, and if so, doing something) is going to be repeated in quite a few controllers in my project.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you mean by "checking whether a field has changed", but I'm still not making the connection.  Angular automatically provides two way binding through `ng-model`, so any property bound to it is always going to be up to date, you don't need to "check to see if it really changed";  here, you seem to be trying to use a DOM element that is outside angular to decide if you need to update something inside angular, which doesn't feel right.  if you want to know if something changed, you can use `$watch` on that property, but you don't need to constantly check everything...

Comment: @Claies Ah, I see the confusion. Yes, I know I can have two-way binding via ng-model. Maybe a use case will clear this up a bit. I'm creating a form that has an email field. I want the controller to call a webservice when the email is changed, to verify that they haven't already registered. I could do this with ng-change, but the problem there is that that would be called every time they type a character. I don't want that. I want the function to be called once the entire value is entered into the field. The only way I can know that is if they leave the field (on blur). Does that make sense?

Comment: aha, now that I can answer :)

Comment: I know the answer I provided here doesn't cover every option, or fix the original code you implemented, but I think it might give you some ideas on the possibilities angular provides for your task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use proper controllerAs notation, not `$scope.vm = this;`:

```
ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm"
```

Then don't mix custom directive with native `onchange` event handler - this is the reason why you get `undefined` error. Name your directive something like `onChange` and use `on-change` attribute instead.

Correct code would look like:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

var Directives;
(function (Directives) {
    function OnChange() {
        var directive = {};
        directive.restrict = "A";
        directive.scope = {
            onChange: '&'
        };
        directive.link = function (scope, elm) {
            elm.bind('blur', function () {
                var currentValue = elm.val();
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.onChange({
                        newValue: currentValue
                    });
                });
            });
        };
        return directive;
    }
    Directives.onChange = OnChange;
})(Directives || (Directives = {}));

app.directive("onChange", Directives.onChange);


var Controllers;
(function (Controllers) {
    var MyCtrl = (function () {
        function MyCtrl($scope) {

        }

        MyCtrl.prototype.callback = function (newValue) {
            alert(newValue);
        };

        return MyCtrl;
    })();
    Controllers.MyCtrl = MyCtrl;
})(Controllers || (Controllers = {}));

app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    return new Controllers.MyCtrl($scope);
}]);
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/9Ltyru6a/5/

Answer (score 1):

If the intent of your code is to only update your controller value on blur, rather than update it on every keypress, angular has `ngModelOptions` for this use.  For example:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.name" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" />
```

you could even provide a debounce, or a button to clear the value....

```
<form name="userForm">
  <input type="text" name="userName" 
         ng-model="user.name" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />

  <button ng-click="userForm.userName.$rollbackViewValue(); user.name=''">Clear</button>
</form>
```

In these cases, if you were to supply an `ng-change`, it would only trigger on the blur event, or after the debounce.

You can also write directives that directly leverage the `$validators` or `$asyncValidators` from the `ngModelController`

here's an example from the Angular [Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#!):

```
app.directive('username', function($q, $timeout) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
    var usernames = ['Jim', 'John', 'Jill', 'Jackie'];

      ctrl.$asyncValidators.username = function(modelValue, viewValue) {

        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          // consider empty model valid
          return $q.when();
        }

        var def = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function() {
          // Mock a delayed response
          if (usernames.indexOf(modelValue) === -1) {
            // The username is available
            def.resolve();
          } else {
            def.reject();
          }

        }, 2000);

        return def.promise;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<div>
    Username:
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="name" username />{{name}}<br />
    <span ng-show="form.name.$pending.username">Checking if this name is available...</span>
    <span ng-show="form.name.$error.username">This username is already taken!</span>
</div>
```

You could of course add the `ng-model-options` to ensure that this triggers only once.

Comment: This is great! I had no idea most of this even existed. Technically, the other answer actually answered the question, but I'm actually going to end up using this. Thanks so much, and sorry if I wasn't very clear in the comments.

Comment: @Kith no need to apologize; Angular is a massive framework with many hidden features, it's not always easy to express exactly what you need.  I could tell well enough though that what you thought was the only way wasn't really ideal, and wanted to take the time to help you get to the other side of that.

Comment: This was so much easier hah. Thanks again.